# ASN source code unexpected TOK_capitalreference, expecting '}'

Tags: c, asn.1

While completion ASN.1 source code giving error: "ASN.1 grammar parse error near line 19 (token "IDENTIFIED"): syntax error, unexpected TOK_capitalreference, expecting '}'
Cannot parse "test.asn""

---

```
RSI DEFINITIONS AUTOMATIC TAGS ::= BEGIN

MessageFrame ::= SEQUENCE {
    messageId       MESSAGE-ID-AND-TYPE.&id({MessageTypes}),
    value           MESSAGE-ID-AND-TYPE.&Type({MessageTypes}{@.messageId})
}

MESSAGE-ID-AND-TYPE ::= CLASS {
    &id         RSImsgID UNIQUE,
    &Type
} WITH SYNTAX { &Type IDENTIFIED BY &id }

MessageTypes MESSAGE-ID-AND-TYPE ::= {
    { Message1      IDENTIFIED BY message1 } | 
    { Message2  IDENTIFIED BY message2 }
}

Message1 ::= SEQUENCE {
    msgCnt          MsgCount,
    id          TemporaryID
}

Message2 ::= SEQUENCE {
    msgCnt          MsgCount,
    id          TemporaryID
}

TemporaryID ::= OCTET STRING (SIZE(4))
MsgCount ::= INTEGER (0..127)
RSImsgID ::= INTEGER (0..32767)
message1    RSImsgID ::= 0 --'00'H
message2    RSImsgID ::= 1 --'01'H
END
```

---

The compiler displays syntax error.
Kindly help me What I am missing in that.

Answer (score 3):

It seems you are using the [Lev Walkin's asn1c compiler](https://github.com/vlm/asn1c) which unfortunately does not yet fully support Information Object Class.

There is a [pending pull request #99](https://github.com/vlm/asn1c/pull/99) that you could try with. See also github [issue #108](https://github.com/vlm/asn1c/issues/108)

**UPDATE 2019-04-11**

Parsing of `Information Object Class` and `Information Object Set` has been finished and merged in the `master` branch in [PR #154](https://github.com/vlm/asn1c/pull/154)

Here is how to compile and test the above ASN.1 definition with the current `master` branch ([commit 88ed3b5c](https://github.com/vlm/asn1c/commit/88ed3b5cf012918bc1084b606b0624c45e0d2191))

```sh
$ asn1c test.asn
$ make -f converter-example.mk
$ ./converter-example -pMessageFrame -iber <(echo 3010800100a10b3009800101810411223344 | xxd -r -p) -o xer
```

```xml
<MessageFrame>
    <messageId>0</messageId>
    <value>
        <Message1>
            <msgCnt>1</msgCnt>
            <id>11 22 33 44</id>
        </Message1>
    </value>
</MessageFrame>
```

```sh
$ ./converter-example -pMessageFrame -iber <(echo 3010800100a10b3009800101810411223344 | xxd -r -p) -o text
MessageFrame ::= {
    messageId: 0
    value: Message1 ::= {
        msgCnt: 1
        id: 11 22 33 44
    }
}
```

If the `master` branch does not work for you try with `vlm_master` branch from  [mouse07410's frok](https://github.com/mouse07410/asn1c/)

Answer (score 1):

The schema is compiled correctly using http://asn1-playground.oss.com/.
Most probably, the compiler you are using is not properly implementing the `WITH SYNTAX` feature. You can try to modify the schema so that you are not using `WITH SYNTAX` and write your object set initialization using the standard syntax, i.e.:

```
MESSAGE-ID-AND-TYPE ::= CLASS {
    &id         RSImsgID UNIQUE,
    &Type
}

MessageTypes MESSAGE-ID-AND-TYPE ::= {
    { &Type Message1, &id message1 } | 
    { &Type Message2, &id message2 }
}
```

Comment: The `WYTH SYNTAX` feature is supported for example by the commercial OSS ASN.1 tools (www.oss.com). I do not understand your second question.

Comment: I have downloaded free version OSS ASN.1 tool but how to compile asn file and how to install that tool ? I am not aware that process.

Comment: If you are using Windows, the downloaded package should be a standard installer, which works just like for any other software. After that you can use the included ASN.1 Studio IDE, which will help you to edit and compile the schema.